# Is there a website I can go to that will tell me if I am running Internet Explorer in Compatibility Mode?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, quickbooks

When I go to http://whatbrowser.org/ in Internet Explorer, it reports IE 10. When I go to the same website using Quickbooks' internal web browser, it reports IE7. I want to know if it is actually IE10 in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Compatibility mode simply changes the `User-Agent` field and disables some of the "features" that would otherwise break older websites and code. Quickbooks probably uses `iehtml.dll` for its HTML rendering which is the usual suspect.